# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request blazor site

Tags: sql, error-handling, blazor

`InvalidOperationException`: Cannot provide a value for property `DatabaseService` on type `WeShareCpoy.Pages.FetchData`.

There is no registered service of type `DatabaseService`.

Here is the code that I get error with.

```
public class DatabaseService
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DatabaseService(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }
```

Sync =

```
    public async Task<List<Item>> GetItems()
    {
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Items", connection);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    Item item = new Item
                    {
                        Bought = reader.GetString(0),
                        WhoBought = reader.GetString(1),
                        Price = reader.GetDecimal(2)
                    };
                    items.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        return items;
    }
```

Another one for add items

```
    public async Task AddItem(Item item)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Items (Bought,WhoBought, Price, ) VALUES (@Bought, @WhoBought, @Price)", connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bought", item.Bought);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhoBought", item.WhoBought);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", item.Price);

            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }
```

Another for update

```
    public async Task UpdateItem(Item item)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Items SET Bought = @Bought, Price = @Price, WhoBought = @WhoBought WHERE Bought = @Bought", connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bought", item.Bought);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", item.Price);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhoBought", item.WhoBought);

            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }
```

One for delete items

```
    public async Task DeleteItem(string bought)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Items WHERE Bought = @Bought", connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bought", bought);

            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WeShareCpoy
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    // Register the database service
                    services.AddScoped<DatabaseService>();

                    // Configure the database service
                    services.AddDbContext<DatabaseService>(options =>
                    {
                        options.UseSqlServer(hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
                    });

                });
    }
}
```

[Check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxKHI.png)

A confusing error for an beginner, its like a blue screen open end error...

Comment: Have you registered DatabaseService in Program.cs?

Comment: no, how do i registere databaseservice?

Comment: nope there isnt any error, that what makes it more confusing...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to register DatabaseService in your Project.

Add the code below in `Program.cs` (For .NET 5 and earlier versions add it inside the Main method).

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<DatabaseService>();
```

Comment: ive added 

            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

And

                    services.AddScoped<DatabaseService>();
                    services.AddDbContext<DatabaseService>(options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

Comment: no, the site doesnt even come up when i start the program

Comment: Can you edit your post and place the contents of Program.cs?